# mysql query for tables having a common normalization table

Tags: mysql

I have have three tables

table1  is a common normalized table for the other tables where the 'id' is foreign key to the other tables

table1

---

```
     id     type         value
    --------------------------- 
     1      category    patient
     2      category    control 
     3      pain        mild  
     4      pain        severe 
     5      pain        normal
     6      pelvic_pain mild
     7      pelvic_pain normal
     8      pelvic_pain severe
```

table2

---

```
    id | patient_code | category_id | pain_id
    ------------------------------------
    1     asd1          1              5
    2     asd2          1              4
    3     asd3          2              3
```

table3

---

```
    id | patient_id | pelvic_pain_id  
    ------------------------------
    1     1            6             
    2     2            6  
    3     3            8
```

I want to do mysql query to get the following denormalized output

output

---

```
    id | patient_code | category |     pain    | pelvic_pain
    --------------------------------------------------------
    1     asd1          patient        severe     mild
    2     asd2          patient        severe     severe
    3     asd3          control        mild       severe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/817b8/2

```
SELECT t2.id,
       t2.patient_code,
       t1.value category,
       t1_.value pain,
       t1_3.value pelvic_pain

FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.category_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table1 t1_
ON t2.pain_id = t1_.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
ON t2.id = t3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN table1 t1_3
ON t3.pelvic_pain_id = t1_3.id
```